# Convert 05-Dec-2013 05:33:10 PM to Boost ptime

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I wanted to know if there was a way to convert the string

```
28-Dec-2013 05:33:10 PM
```

to ptime ??

I tried doing something like this

```
ptime time(time_from_string("28-Dec-2013 05:33:10 PM"));
```

But that doesnt work ?

Any suggestions ??

I tried the following also

```
       boost::posix_time::ptime abs_time;
       std::string mydate = "28-Dec-2013 05:33:10 PM";

       boost::posix_time::time_input_facet *tif = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p");
       std::istringstream iss(mydate);
       iss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), tif));
       iss >> abs_time;
```

However when I cout `abs_time` I get `a not-a-date-time`

Comment: Have a look at date input facets: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.date_input_facet

Comment: From the docs: `!` _Signifies flags that currently do not work for input._  So, `%I` and `%P` are currently not supported.  That's unfortunate.